# How can i send an ajax call to the server and inserting data in my database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 3 buttons each button means a type of error :

```
<button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 1</button>
<button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 2</button>
<button id="E1_<?= $c['code'] ?>">Type error 3</button>
```

This's my table :

```
  CREATE TABLE button_check
   (
      code varchar(255),
      button_1 int(11),
      button_2 int(11),
      button_3 int(11)
   );
```

//Click & De-click :

```
$(function()
 {

 jQuery.fn.clickToggle = function(d,c){
    function cb(){ [d,c][this._tog^=1].call(this); }
    return this.on("click", cb);
 };

var all_errors = {'E1':0,'E2':0,'E3':0};

var btn1 = false;
btn2 = false;
btn3 = false;

  $("[id^='E1_']").clickToggle(function(){
    all_errors.E1++;
    console.log(errors);
},function(){
    if(all_errors .E1 > 0) all_errors .E1--;
});

});


  $.ajax({ url: 'data_insert.php',
   data: {id: value,value: all_errors},
   type: 'post',
   success: function(output) {
     console.log(output);
   }
```

data_insert.php :

```
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $value = $_POST['value'];
    try {      
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,  $password);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO button_check (code,button_1, button_2,button_3) VALUES ('$code','$btn1', 'btn2', 'btn3')";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    catch(PDOException $e)
     {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
     }
    }
```

I want to send an ajax call and insert all clicks in my table.

Please i need help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stack overflow is not for `how to's`. If you would like to post some of your code, I will be able to help you. Otherwise, I will not post code.

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: @Robert i add my code.

Comment: You didn't connect to the database, and you didn't execute the command.

Comment: Still haven't connected.

Comment: @Robert i add a database connection.

Comment: @AlokPatel when i add ajax call i can't click.

Comment: when using pdo. the execute command is `execute()` not `exec()`

Comment: @Robert I modified. Now when I click on the buttons , it does not count against if I remove that part "$.ajax({ url: 'data_insert.php',
   data: {id: value,value: all_errors},
   type: 'post',
   success: function(output) {
     console.log(output);
   }"      it relies on my browser console

Comment: @Robert if you know my problem,can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You will do something like jquery post $.post to the php file. The file will read the post contents and insert into database.

//jquery code

```
$.post('insert.php', {data:data}, function(raw){
//success here 
});
```

//insert.php

```
$dataJSON = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($dataJSON);
//setup connection and do insert with that data
```